# AVPlayer addObserver never being called

Tags: swift, avplayer

I'm trying to get AVPlayer timedMetadata but the observer is never being called

```
self.metaItem!.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "metaData", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions(), context: nil)
        metPlayer=AVPlayer(playerItem: metaItem)
        metPlayer.play()
...

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change:
        [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if keyPath != "metaData" { return }
        print("...")
    }
```

but MPMoviePlayerController works fine

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`metaItem` AVPlayerItem should observe for key path *[timedMetadata](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayeritem/1389602-timedmetadata)*, but not *"metaData"*:

```
self.metaItem!.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "timedMetadata", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions(), context: nil)
```